# Where to download a Microsoft PXE image?

Tags: linux, windows, iso-image, bootable-media, pxe

When I look for a Microsoft [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PXE) image to download I can only find different tools which will build a PXE image.

Is it still possible to simply download a Microsoft PXE image directly?

Looking to make a bootable thumb drive from an ISO for installing Windows.  I'm currently using Linux.

Comment: "Is it still possible to simply download a Microsoft PXE image directly?" - No; You need to create it yourself. You can use one of Microsoft's free Windows 11 VMs to accomplish this within Windows since it cannot be accomplished from within L:inux

Comment: Use Ventoy, it's as simple as that. PXE is for network installations, not really what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The PXE-bootable file for Windows operating systems can be found in the downloadable ISO image. You can download that [here for Windows 11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11), or by using the Media Creation Tool.

The image file will be in `/Sources/Boot.wim`