# What path to write a Windows ISO to create a bootable thumb drive?

Tags: linux, windows, bootable-media, dd, dualboot

Was [looking](https://superuser.com/q/1830968/977796) to use PXE, but now just directly downloading the Windows 10 ISO as:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ll /media/nicholas/
total 18
drwxr-x---+ 5 root     root        5 Feb 19 18:23  ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root        4 Jan 25 12:11  ../
dr-xr-xr-x  6 nicholas nicholas  492 May  5  2023  CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 nicholas nicholas 2048 Apr 18  2023 'Ubuntu 23.04 amd64'/
drwxrwxrwx  1 nicholas nicholas 4096 Feb 19 18:15  win/
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ ll /media/nicholas/win/
total 13
drwxrwxrwx  1 nicholas nicholas 4096 Feb 19 18:15 ./
drwxr-x---+ 5 root     root        5 Feb 19 18:23 ../
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

thumb drive:

[image: thumb]

I've tried:

```
sudo dd if=/home/nicholas/Desktop/Win10_22H2_English_x64v1.iso of=/media/nicholas/win/ bs=4M && sync
```

but that doesn't seem to work as it's a directory.  How do I find the path to write to?  The mount command returns many results.

Comment: its been a long time since I tried to do something like this. but conceptually, you cannot write the image of a full disk (partition table, etc) while the device is mounted. so you need to find the device name (eg \dev\sdc or whatever), unmount any volumes,  and dd to the device. note that it should not be to a particular volume on the device (like \dev\sdc1). you will probably have to remove and reconnect the disk after compliion, or reboot before you see the new filesystem

Comment: If it's a real ISO (e.g. downloaded from Microsoft; as opposed to an image of a USB (properly created with Media Creation Tool) just freely named `.iso` while it's not an ISO), then [simply `dd`-ing to USB won't work](https://superuser.com/a/1527373/432690).

Comment: This is in a nutshell the same or a follow up to [Where to download a Microsoft PXE image?](https://superuser.com/questions/1830968/where-to-download-a-microsoft-pxe-image) . Again, PXE is for network installations, not what you're looking for. Use Ventoy and be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, 'ISO' files **are not disk images; they're CD/DVD images** – don't assume that they're compatible with other kinds of disks unless their author says that they are. (Linux 'ISO' images are specifically prepared using isohybrid for that kind of usage, but that doesn't work for other operating systems.) See [yesterday's thread](https://superuser.com/a/1830858/1686) about copying Windows.iso to a thumbdrive.

So none of the below will be *useful* in this case; it's just for reference.

> but that doesn't seem to work as it's a directory. How do I find the path to write to? The `mount` command returns many results.

- When using `mount`, look specifically **for the result that mentions "/media/nicholas"**. There will generally be only one such item in the output. (Use `findmnt` for a more readable format.)

  ```
  $ mount | grep nicholas
  /dev/sde2 on /media/nicholas type vfat (etc,etc,etc)
  ```
- Another way to do that is `df /media/nicholas` or `findmnt -T /media/nicholas` which will generally output just the line you need.
- Another, much easier way is to look at the output of `lsblk`:

  ```
  $ lsblk
  NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
  sde           8:0    1  15.6G  0 disk  /media/nicholas
  sdd           8:48   0   5.5T  0 disk
  └─sdd1        8:51   0   5.5T  0 part  /data
  ```
- Or even `lsblk -S`:

  ```
  $ lsblk -S
  NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL  REV SERIAL            TRAN
  sda  0:0:0:0    disk General  UDisk 5.00 General_UDisk-0:0 usb
  ```

With some of the above commands, the result might point to a partition device such as "sda2"; in that case remove the number to get the **whole-disk device** such as "sda". Disk images are practically always whole-disk – they bring their own MBR, their own partition table, etc.

As noted in the comments, don't forget to **`umount`** the filesystem first, otherwise it might corrupt the image you wrote (or the opposite, the image might crash the OS when the filesystem tries to make sense of it).

Finally, you could also just click "**Open in Disks**" which then offers you the menu option "Restore from image", which does the same thing as `dd`.