# How to put Windows 10 on a thumb drive with Ventoy to install?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, iso-image, ventoy

As [suggested](https://superuser.com/q/1830971/977796), I've [downloaded Ventoy](https://github.com/ventoy/Ventoy) and did run the shell script.  It's not clear to me what "install ventoy" does, but I did install it to a USB stick.  How would I then get Windows 10 onto the thumb drive itself?

This is from Linux.

Comment: Please clarify the question: do you mean to simply put the ISO image on the drive, or make bootable Windows 10 installation media, or to make a drive with bootable, persistent, Windows operating system (as with Hasleo's WinToUSB)?

Comment: bootable.  I'm not sure what those other are.  Would you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Bootable simply means that some software on the USB runs; it might be for just the purpose of **installing** Windows 10 and does **nothing else**. A bootable, persistent, operating system is the full Windows 10 on that drive, able to run applications and retain data (see https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/index.html). **Pleasse edit your question** to clarify the purpose -- Ventoy might not be suitable.

Comment: thanks for explaining -- I'm just looking to install only https://superuser.com/q/1831084/977796 and so perhaps ventoy isn't suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just drag the ISO onto the mounted thumb drive.

Apparently you can put as many ISO's as will fit.

Comment: Exactly! Everything is explained it their website. Also in more than one comment under your questions. This really shouldn't have been a question.